# How to write to ContactStore.Contact.Phones?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, windows-10-mobile

From my app I create contacts using `StoredContact` and the `ContactStore`, setting the mobile phone number using `KnwonContactProperties.MobileTelephone` via `GetPropertiesAsync`.

This is fine, and I can see the mobile phone number in People.

But...

If I try to access the contacts programatically via `ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync`, I *don't* see this phone number in the contact.Phones collection.

Is there any way to get numbers written into the Phones collection?

([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39072385/which-phone-number-does-whatsapp-look-for-in-windows-10))

Comment: PS: I'd like this to be able to work on 8.1 and 10...

Answer (score 1):

The [KnownContactProperties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207655.aspx) class is in under `Windows.Phone.PhoneContract`namespace, but [ContactManager.RequestStoreAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn624858.aspx) is under Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts namespace. It may be the reason you cannot get the phone numbers. [ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj207573.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method under `Windows.Phone.PhoneContract` same with KnownContactProperties can work well. Here is a completed demo for inserting a contact and then get the contact's name and phone number.

XAML Code

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtName" Header="name" InputScope="NameOrPhoneNumber"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtTel" Header="phone number 1" InputScope="ChineseHalfWidth"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtTel1" Header="phone number 2" InputScope="TelephoneNumber"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnSave" Content="Save" Click="btnSave_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="btnGet" Content="GET" Click="btnGet_Click"/> 
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind

```
 private async void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var name = txtName.Text;
     var tel = txtTel.Text;

     ContactStore contactStore = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync(ContactStoreSystemAccessMode.ReadWrite, ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode.ReadOnly);
     ContactInformation contactInformation = new ContactInformation();
     contactInformation.DisplayName = name;
     var contactProps = await contactInformation.GetPropertiesAsync();
     contactProps.Add(KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone, tel);
     StoredContact storedContact = new StoredContact(contactStore, contactInformation);
     await storedContact.SaveAsync();
 }

 private async void btnGet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {

     ContactStore contactStore = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync(ContactStoreSystemAccessMode.ReadWrite, ContactStoreApplicationAccessMode.ReadOnly);
     var result = contactStore.CreateContactQuery();
     var count = await result.GetContactCountAsync();
     var list = await result.GetContactsAsync();
     foreach (var item in list)
     {
         var properties = await item.GetPropertiesAsync();
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.DisplayName);                
         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(properties[KnownContactProperties.MobileTelephone].ToString());
     }
 }
```

Comment: Hm, thanks for trying. Unfortunately what I need to do is the opposite: be able to write to `Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts`, or at least find someway of writing into the `.Phones` property of the Contact there. The reason is that (as far as I can tell) *that* is where WhatsApp is looking, and I want WhatsApp to be able to detect the contacts that my App is creating...

Comment: Have you checked this official sample:https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/ContactCardIntegration. This sample have code about writing contact to `windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts`, did you have problems when using it ? It use [contactphone class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.contacts.contactphone)

Comment: Actually I think I may misunderstand you. You set the phone property with `KnwonContactProperties.MobileTelephone ` which is come from `Windows.Phone.PhoneContract`. But now you said you want to set the phone property with `windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts`. Have  you test my code? The code list the contacts created by the app.

Comment: My app (which started on 8.1) currently writes using `Windows.Phone`, and the contacts and numbers show up fine in People. But WhatsApp can't 'see' the phone numbers for some reason. I created a contact directly in People, and WhatsApp could see the number. Subsequently, using `Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts` I saw that the number was visible on the contact. Thus I suppose that that is where WhatsApp is looking, so I want to write there. I've seen your link, but it says Win 10 only, I hope that's just for building, and doesn't mean it won't work on 8.1...

Comment: Why you say  WhatsApp can't 'see' the phone numbers for some reason.? In my code, I print out the phone number result in console. My code sample can work on 8.1 as well as 10

Comment: Sunteen, I have no idea, all I know is that if you have a contact created by the Windows.Phone.PhoneContract route, WhatsApp will see the contact, but not the number (on my Win 10 in any case). Of course this is most probably a bug in WhatsApp, but I can't do anything about that!

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the github example is effectively win10 only :(